# how to draw 3d RGBA point on stage not using 3d engines?

Tags: flash, actionscript, 3d, draw, point

So we have values generator that outputs someting like `FF00FF5F`. We have some coordinates like `50, 300, 10`. We want to draw a point in 3d on stage. Not using PV3d or anething like that. thay say there is going to be no default z sorting but I can live with that... (I mean we opened new `.fla` doc in flash, pressed f9 and started coding, sorry - I am new to flash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var desiredColour:uint = 0xFF00FF5F;
var desired_x:Number = 50;
var desired_y:Number = 300;
var desired_z:Number = 10;


var pointGraphicData = new BitmapData(1,1,true,desiredColour)
var pointGraphic:Bitmap = new Bitmap(pointGraphicData);

pointGraphic.x = desired_x;
pointGraphic.y = desired_y;
pointGraphic.z = desired_z;

addChild(pointGraphic);
```

That will place a coloured 1x1 bitmap onstage in the provided x/y/z position.